# How can I truly shut down ssh server?

Tags: systemd, sshd

I disable the ssh server with systemctl disable ssh then reboot. After reboot, I still can log into the remote server through ssh. I use systemctl status ssh to check the server status and it is inactive.

```
$ systemctl -a | grep ssh
ssh.service                                               loaded    inactive dead      OpenBSD Secure Shell server
ssh@3-192.168.0.120:22-192.168.0.104:31079.service        loaded    active   running   OpenBSD Secure Shell server per-connection daemon (192.168.0.104:31079)
system-ssh.slice                                          loaded    active   active    system-ssh.slice
ssh.socket                                                loaded    active   listening OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `systemctl status ssh` to your question?

Comment: It is much like:`● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-07-09 23:25:16 CST; 1s ago`

Comment: Additionally you should block port 22 on the firewall, so that even if the SSH server is running somehow, it won't be accessible from remote.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The systemd SSH socket is active, and the SSH service is socket-activated. You need to disable the socket as well:

```
systemctl disable --now ssh.socket
```

In fact, on my Arch system, the sshd daemon runs only when a new connection comes in. At other times, the only instances of sshd are the child processes forked off to handle those connections.

Also see:

- [systemd and socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html)

Comment: @spender that's Lennart Poettering's official blog, so it's hard to get a 'better' source than that. Not sure why you're getting a warning from Firefox, but I'm not

Comment: Ah, you're probably getting a warning about his self-signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks all. @muru is right. `HTTPS Everywhere` punted me over to the HTTPS version. That's an interesting error message for a certificate error. Now I'm trying to figure out how to un-dumb down my error messages.

Comment: @spender: Indeed the error message is utterly awful. It should be telling you not to submit private data to the site, not that "hackers can steal your [implied: at-rest] data if you visit the site". It reads like a scareware/fake-AV message which users should be *trained to ignore*.

Comment: Now that Lets Encrypt is so easy to use, Poettering should use it instead of self-signed certificates. :/

Comment: BTW, how is this not miserably slow? AIUI sshd has to do some significant cryptographic computations on startup, which would happen at connection time with such a socket-activation setup.

Comment: @R.. Host key generation, if that's what you're referring to, is only done once (and you really don't want your SSH server doing it on every start anyway). I can't think of any other cryptographic computations that the SSH server would need to do that aren't directly tied to one specific connection.

Comment: @aCVn: I'm obviously not referring to host key generation. IIRC it's generation of an ephemeral key/secret used for negotiating connections, that's frequently replaced, but I forget the details. On a fast machine it's probably only a few tens or hundreds of ms, but I'd consider that a pretty miserable conenction delay (on top of other basic, non-cryptographic delays from starting a new process).

Comment: @muru give Poettering a tad bit of time - it takes time to integrate a CA into an init manager....